# Why does not one of my Xmonad managehooks show any effect?

Tags: xmonad

Here is my config:
https://gist.github.com/378fd12feaf94127393b

No matter what actions I define for windows with a specified class, they are never applied.

Comment: Not sure but mine works, you can take a look at it if you want: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/Robert_Massaioli's_xmonad.hs I'll try and look more into this soon.

Comment: Actually one suggestion, instead of doShift try 'doF $ S.shift' where S is 'XMonad.StackSet'